# Django Channel web sockets - append message to Model.objects

Tags: django, django-models, websocket, django-channels

Lately, I've been investigating onto integrating web sockets into Django. According to the documentation, using [Channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) is the way to go.

Given an illustrative model *Query*

```
class Request(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(name="id", primary_key=True)
    query = models.CharField(name = 'query', max_length=1024)
```

I want to have my web application connected to a web socket server. When the web socket server receives a message, it should broadcast that message to a particular subset of socket connections established by the client.

The client (namely web browser), once receiving the broadcasted message, it should append it to *Request.objects*. From there on, the list of all queries should be automatically updated using Django templates and within it the defined model - without forcing the user to explicitly refresh it.

Hence, the questions of mine are: (I) using Channels (if this is the preferred way of dealing web socket connections in Django), how can I append the newly arrived *Query* object to *Query.objects* - without storing the object into the database because it has already been inserted prior sending to the web socket server, (II) refresh the content of the corresponding Django template.

Answer (score 0):

Django-Channels is new way for connecting Django backend to Django frontend.

Your second question I'm not understand fully but inside the consumer functions you can import the models and update the database

```
# consumers.py 
def hello(message):
    obj = Request.objects..
    obj.save()
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
```

And finally you can update the template using jquery...

```
<p></p>
socket.onmessage = function(e) {
    $('p').html(e.data);
}
```